# Nothing happens when clicking Update to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, updates

I am on Ubuntu 10.10 and each time I boot my OS it asks me to if I want to update to 11.04. I click "yeah, why not". It downloads 2 files, asks my password and that's all. Nothing happens.

**EDIT**

Ok, I've ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and get downloadings and settings and after few seconds it stops after

```
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

**UPD 2**

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release i386 (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

Comment: It starts downloading. I'll write when something happen :) Thanx

Comment: Ok... It was fast: it stopped after `ldconfig deferred processing now taking place`.

Comment: Possibly you have either synaptic or update-manager running.  if you run  ps -ef | grep synaptic      or      ps -ef | grep update     do you see more that one process running?

Comment: only update-notifier is working

Comment: What do you mean by "update-notifier" - make sure you close down all applications such as firefox?  if you do a standard sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade   does this complete OK?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep update` returns only `update-notifier`. `apt-get update &&...` finished without errors and without any changes

Comment: @fossfreedom, I've clicked "About Ubuntu" and it says that I am on 11.04 already - but here is no any changes (here is no any Unity at least)

Comment: Open up synaptic manager - search for a natty package version such as xserver-xorg-video-intel  it should be at version 2:2.14.0-4ubuntu7.1

Comment: I can't open synaptic... Nothing happens when I click on it :) I've broke my Ubuntu

Comment: hmmm - please edit your question with the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Done. /etc/apt/sources.list is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
  it appears your package management system is a little screwed up.

edit your sources.list and # out the following entry (it isnt a standard repository that I recognise):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

save then

See if the following cleans up the package management system:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall --purge install update-manager
update-manager
```

Comment: still the same situation

Comment: Looks I am going to just reinstall it from scratch

Comment: hmmm - I think you may be correct - If you've got an external drive/USB stick, backup your important files and do a fresh Natty install.